# Configure One to One relationship in Hibernate 5 being able to ASSIGN the child entity by ID

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

Assuming that we have two entity classes Project and TeamLead as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "dbo.projects", schema = "data_source")
public class Project {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "project_id")
    private int project_id;

    @Column(name = "project_name")
    private String project_name;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "lead_id")
    private TeamLead team_lead;

    //Getters and setters
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "dbo.teamleads", schema = "data_source")
public class TeamLead {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "project_id")
    private int lead_id;

    @Column(name = "lead_name")
    private String lead_name;

    //Getters and setters
}
```

The insertion of a TeamLead in the database is independent of the Project. We have a predefined list of TeamLeads, and each TeamLead can be assigned to one project.

A Project is created through a web form, and the following JSON is sent to the Controller:

```
{"project_name": "Random Name", "techLead": 1} 
// Assuming that we have stored in the database a TeamLead with id 1
```

I expected the given TechLead to be assigned to the newly created project, but insted I get this exception:

```
Could not read document: Can not construct instance of models.TeamLead: 
no int/Int-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from Number value (1)
```

*NOTE: If i change the annotation from @JoinColumn to @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn it works, but if a Project is DELETED, then the TeamLead is also deleted.

What should I do?

Comment: You didn't talk about the important part: the part that gets the JSON, parses it, finds the team lead identified by the given ID, checks that it isn't assigned to a project already, and creates the project with the tech lead found in the database. That won't happen by magic.

Comment: In the controller I use a @RequestBody annotation that automatically maps the Json to the Project entity, so I can't interfere there. That's why I expected it to be done by the framework.

Comment: Well, you can't. As the error message says, the number `1` can't be deserialized to an instance of Project coming from your database. At least not without you seriously customizing the deserialization. Map your JSON to a Java object that has the same structure as your JSON, then do what I suggested in my previous comment.

Comment: Yes, that will work. Thank you for yourfeedback!